# Run Angular CLI Lint without Angular CLI?

Tags: angular-cli

Anyone know how to run Angular CLI lint directly with tslint?

Things I've tried at the root level of my CLI directory:

`tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json`

`tslint -p src/tsconfig.app.json -c tslint.json`

`tslint --project src/tsconfig.app.json`

In Visual Code studio I'm seeing an Angular CLI (node_module/codelyzer) specific error. And with `ng lint` I'm seeing it too.

Anyway to get the same behavior outside of Angular CLI?

Comment: See: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/cli/. What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: That's the thing. No errors. It just runs successfully. If I have a tslint rule error, that'll show up. It's just not processing the angluar CLI rules like `ng lint` does.

Comment: When I run `tslint -c .\tslint.json 'src/**/*.ts'` against an ng/cli project I have, the output is similar to what I get using `ng lint`, expect I get some additional warnings when using tslint directly. You just want them to act the same, no matter the tool, right?